# Are these two methods for setting pointers equal to each other the same?

Tags: c, pointers

I am curious, if I have two pointers

```
int *x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
int *y;
```

and I want y to point to the address of x, is

```
y = x;
```

the same as

```
y = &*x;
```

?

Comment: AFAIK, yes. *x is an lvalue, &*x is its address, which is x. there should be no side effects involved.

Comment: (The real question is, of course, what happens when `x==NULL`)

Comment: @Elazar: It doesn't matter. It doesn't crash.

Comment: @anishsane I think you are right, but I will be happy to see a proof. (Not an example).

Comment: ^^@Elazar: Tested with `gcc -S`. But indeed, I will be surprised if some compiler does treat them differently.

Comment: Why would you want to write `y = &*x;` in the first place?

Comment: I was curious if there was a difference.

Comment: @KeithThompson If I'm remembering my work with LLVM correctly, when you're writing C++ code, `x` is an iterator, and `y` is a pointer to be returned from a C-interfacing method. Unfortunately I don't have my code with me at the moment to check if I am remembering that correctly, so a comment from someone with more C++ knowledge would be appreciated.

Comment: Neither one of those assignments results in y "point[ing] to the address of x".  Both of them set y equal to x.  That is, they both point to the allocated object.  To a C or C++ programmer, "the address of x" is generally interpretted as `&x`, not the address that x points to.

Comment: @JAB: The question is tagged C, not C++, which is why I didn't mention C++ rules. In C++, if `x` is an iterator, then `*x` invokes a user-defined (well, probably library-defined) overloaded operator, and any rules about collapsing `&*x` to `x` would not apply. Of course C++ has C-style pointers and built-in unary `&` and `*` operators. C++ has not adopted C's special-case rule for `&*x`. In any case, given the declaration `int *x;`, `x` is an ordinary pointer, not an iterator. If you have a question about C++ iterators, feel free to post it separately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question has two parts, and it's worth noting that they are not both correct:

First, you ask:

> is
>   
>     y = x;
>   
> the same as
>   
>     y = &*x;

Since the dereference (`*`) and address-of (`&`) operators have the same [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) they will bind right to left, so

```
y = &*x;
```

is the same as:

```
y = &(*x);
```

And yes, that will yield the same effect as `y=x;` Now if you have a C compliant compiler that follows the letter of the law, it will not only be the same effectively, it *will* be the same, this is due to section 6.5.3.2 P3 of the C Specification:

> The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type ‘‘type’’,
>   the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’.
>
> If the operand is the result of a unary * operator,
>   neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were
>   omitted

So the compiler will see both the `*` and `&` together and omit them entirely.

---

In the second half of your question you stated:

`I want y to point to the address of x`

Presumably you know that that's not what you're doing, but you're setting `y` to point to *the same address* as `x` instead. `x` of course has its own address and that could be set, but you'd need a different variable `int **y = &x;` assuming `x` is a valid value to be dereferenced.

Comment: @Elazar - `assuming x is a valid value to be dereferenced` is a comment that applies to the whole answer.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know what happens if x is *not* a valid value to be dereferenced. Is it safe? is it UB?

Comment: @Elazar - I'm using it as a blanket statement because it's easier that way, however from a C language point of view (6.5.3.2 P4) it's UB:  `If an
invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is
undefined.`

Comment: Great, thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. So, these expressions are *not* the same.

Comment: If `x` is a null pointer, then `*x` has undefined behavior when the `*` operator is evaluated. In `&*x`, the standard explicitly states that neither `*` nor `&` is evaluated, so there is no undefined behavior; `&*x` is equivalent to `x`, except that it's not an lvalue. (The following statement that "the constraints on the operators still apply" doesn't change that, the requirement that the operand of `*` is not null is not a constraint.) The rule collapsing `&*x` to `x` was added in C99; in C89/C90, there's no such rule, and `&*x` does have undefined behavior if `x` is a null pointer.

Comment: @KeithThompson great. So I understand it is formally equivalent but not in a truly portable way.

Comment: @Elazar - `So, these expressions are not the same` - eer, hang-on there. See my reference to the C spec *in my answer*? That applies first, I think I misunderstood what/why you were asking. Please see the comment from @Keith . I think that clarifies it. Yes `int *x = NULL; int y = *x;` is UB (6.5.3.2 P4). However `int *x = NULL; int *y = &(*x);` is not (6.5.3.2 P3) since the `&*` part will not be evaluated. See the difference?

Comment: @Mike I know the difference; of course `y=*x` is UB but that's not interesting. I understood these expressions are the same based on your comment, not on your updated answer (and Keith's comment). And yes, that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: There is nothing incorrect about the accepted answer. The poster above notes that IF the compiler is up to scratch with respect to 6.5.3.2 P3 of the C standard, this redundancy is removed entirely. If it's not up to standard, then the redundancy is not removed, and my description (ie: indirection then address of) addresses this concern sufficiently without posting pseudo assembly to complement it.

Answer (score 4):

They are **functionally** equivalent. This is effectively a "shallow copy".

So, the following assignments achieve the same final result:

```
y=x;

y=&(*x);
```

However, the second operation will take more time to execute because rather than just a direct assignment, you are performing an **indirection** then an **address-of** operation. The compiler may just optimize this down to `y=x` anyways, depending on your system.

Edit:

---

As the poster below notes, if your compiler supports the C standard, including 6.5.3.2 P3 of the C standard, this will definitely be optimized out, likely at the pre-processor level before the code is even compiled.

Comment: Are you *sure* it will take more time? If they are really euqivalent, it can't be true. An indirection needs an operand.

Comment: `Functionally` equivalent, in the sense of, same resulting values, output, etc. This does not imply they will take the same steps to achieve the same (deterministic) output. I come from a statistics/math background, so I try to be very specific when it comes to this :)

Comment: So what steps are taken, in pseudo-unoptimized-assembly? (Of course the AST is *not* the same.)

Comment: It will depend on your compiler, pre-processor, toolchain, etc. With my current GCC setup, this sort of redundancy is optimized out.

Comment: I talk about *pseudo* assembly. worst case. what can happen.

Comment: `compiler may just optimize this down` - if it's a true C compliant compiler it **will** remove both. That's part of the C specification (see my answer for reference).

Answer (score 3):

They are either exactly the same by definition, or almost the same, depending on which version of the C standard you're dealing with.

In ISO C99 and C11, we have the following wording (quoting the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) C11 draft) in 6.5.3.2:

> The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. If the
>   operand has type "*type*", the result has type "pointer to *type*". If
>   the operand is the result of a unary `*` operator, neither that
>   operator nor the `&` operator is evaluated and the result is as if
>   both were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still
>   apply and the result is not an lvalue.

So given:

```
int *x = /* whatever */;
int *y;
```

these two are exactly equivalent, *even if `x` is a null pointer*:

```
y = x;
y = &*x;
```

Without the special-case rule, the behavior would be undefined, because the behavior of the `*` operator is defined only if its operand is a valid non-null pointer. But since the `*` is never evaluated, it has no behavior here, defined or otherwise. (The fact that, unlike `x`, `&*x` is not an lvalue is not relevant here.)

And in C89/C90, that special-case rule had not yet been added, so the behavior of `&*x` *is* undefined if `x` is a null (or otherwise invalid) pointer.  Most pre-C99 compilers would probably optimize away the `*` and `&` anyway; remember, it's the nature of undefined behavior that something *can* behave just as you might expect it to behave.

On the other hand, there's a very real difference in the behavior of anyone reading the code. If I see `y = x;`, my behavior is to think "Oh, it's an ordinary pointer assignment." If I see `y = &*x;`, my behavior is to think "Why the heck did you write it that way?", and to change it to `y = x;` if I'm in a position to do so.

Comment: Great answer. And, using `y = &*x` is a very good (and harmless) way to say: "Hey, I am new so I don't know what I am doing. Proceed with caution."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although the second one looks like an entry for an obfuscation contest.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are the same, but highly convoluted.

You can test this by doing the following:

```
y = &(*x);
printf("%p\n", (void*)x);
printf("%p\n", (void*)y);
```

Comment: This test doesn't say much. It may just happen to be the case.

Comment: The printed pointer address of X & Y will match, pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Yes, but the question was about the C language, not about a C implementation.

Comment: Actually, printing a variable with the incorrect format string is UB (7.21.6.1 P9), so the test doesn't show anything. Now if you change those to `%p`, then we're talking. ;)

Comment: Still UB. `%p` requires an argument of type `void*`, not `int*`. Cast the argument to `void*` to avoid the UB. (But it still doesn't prove that the behavior is defined; no experiment can do that.)

Comment: @KeithThompson How can it make any difference? And why?

Comment: @Elazar: There's no guarantee that `void*` and `int*` have the same representation, or even if they do that they're passed as arguments to `printf` in the same way. It's likely to work on the vast majority of real-world systems, but it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, they are exactly equivalent. I will be surprised if some compiler does treat them differently.

Because of presense of `&`, `*x` will not be evaluated at all. Hence even if x is null, it will not cause crash / seg-fault. (You can best verify using assembly.)

When we talk of assembly, it's impossible to calculate *x (value) & then &(*x) (pointer).
Hence, compiler will simply calculate the address of *x, without calculating value of *x.

We can also check for more complex cases, like `&(a[10])` It simply translates to `a+10*sizeof(a[0])` in assembly.

Another proof would be the `offsetof` macro, typically defined as:

```
#define offsetof(st, m) ((size_t)(&((st *)0)->m))
```

Here, it's calculating `&(null_pointer->m)`, which does not cause a crash.

Comment: BTW `sizeof` does not count. `sizeof(printf("%d",*(volatile int*)0))` will result in 4 or 8, without any side effects.

Comment: yes, sizeof considers only the data type, not underlying data.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a handy little function that may help. Not sure that you need all of the "includes".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int *x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
int *y = x;
int *z = &*x;

//y = x;
//z = &*x;

 cout   << "x has type: " << typeid(x).name() << '\n'
        << "y has type: " << typeid(y).name() << '\n'
        << "z has type: " << typeid(z).name() << '\n'
        << "values are " << x <<"  "<< y << "  " << z  << '\n'; 
}
```

The result I get from this is:

```
x has type: Pi
y has type: Pi
z has type: Pi
values are 0x1a3a010  0x1a3a010  0x1a3a010
```

The answer then is, Yes, the methods are exactly the same using Ubuntu 14.10, g++

Comment: Could you add a conclusion?